How to profile outgoing requests in Node.js Kinesis SDK
Problem definition
I would like to have an options to observer the timings of each HTTP step (I mean duration of hostname resolving, duration of establishing http connection, time before the first byte was received etc.) while requesting the Kinesis API.
I known that the plain Node.js supports such event mechanism:
const req = request('https://www.google.com')

req.on('socket', socket => {
  socket.once('lookup', (err, address, family, host) => {
    ...
  })
  socket.once('connect', () => {
    ...
  })
})
...

Which makes possible to log / trace timings of the steps.
The question is:
Is there are any mechanism for logging same metrics while using Kinesis SDK?
Simplified example of the code
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    ...
    lookup: tracedDnsLookup, // <----- Custom LookupFunction for measuring DNS lookup timing
});

const kinesisClient = new KinesisClient({
    requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
        connectionTimeout: CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
        httpAgent,
        httpsAgent
    }),
    ...
});

const response = await kinesisClient.send(new PutRecordCommand(input))

